# How to get latitude and longitude values using @react-google-maps/api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to get the latitude and longitude values from the selected place

```
import {
  GoogleMap,
  useJsApiLoader,
  Marker,
  Autocomplete,
} from "@react-google-maps/api";

...

 const { isLoaded, loadError } = useJsApiLoader({
    googleMapsApiKey: `${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}`,
    libraries: ["places"],
  });

  const mapStyles = {
    borderRadius: 9,
    height: height ? height : "100%",
    width: "100%",
  };
  const center = defaultCoords
    ? defaultCoords
    : { lat: 54.599260213253636, lng: -5.89449847266111 };
  const [mapLocation, setMapLocation] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (e: any) => {
    const place = e.target.value;
    console.log("latitude = ", place.geometry.location);
  };

...
...

const renderMap = () => {
    return (
      <>
        {/* <Autocomplete>
          <input placeholder="Enter Partner Location1" className="textfield" />
        </Autocomplete> */}
        <div>
          <Autocomplete>
            <TextFieldComponent
              name="location"
              placeholder="Enter Partner Location"
              labelName="Partner Location"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </Autocomplete>
        </div>
        <GoogleMap
          center={center}
          mapContainerStyle={mapStyles}
          onClick={onClick}
          zoom={zoom ? zoom : 10}
        >
          {children}
          <Marker position={mapLocation ? mapLocation : center} />
        </GoogleMap>
      </>
    );
  };
```

when I console values like this,

> > > "console.log("latitude = ", place.geometry.location);"
> > > It causes an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'location')"

Please give me some suggestions to fix this problem.

Comment: And what is `place`? Can you console.log it?

Comment: const place = e.target.value;

Comment: Yeah but what exactly is that `e.target.value`?

Comment: its the place title from the textfield

Comment: I need its latitude and logitude values, is there any idea to get those?

Comment: What do you expect from user to write in this input?